# Unity animations code

Tags: c#, game, animation, unity3d

I'm currently working on a live keyboard demo on unity. I've animated every key but my script spans over 2000 lines. I'm fairly happy with my script but I know theres better ways to do it.

I have defined functions and if statements for each and every key.

I'll post my code below

```cs
private Animator Alpha1Press;
private Animator Alpha2Press;
private Animator Alpha3Press;
private Animator Alpha4Press;
private Animator Alpha5Press;
private Animator Alpha6Press;
private Animator Alpha7Press;
private Animator Alpha8Press;
private Animator Alpha9Press;
private Animator Alpha0Press;

public void playAlpha1()
{
    Alpha1Press.SetBool("Alpha1Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha1()
{
    Alpha1Press.SetBool("Alpha1Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha2()
{
    Alpha2Press.SetBool("Alpha2Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha2()
{
    Alpha2Press.SetBool("Alpha2Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha3()
{
    Alpha3Press.SetBool("Alpha3Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha3()
{
    Alpha3Press.SetBool("Alpha3Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha4()
{
    Alpha4Press.SetBool("Alpha4Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha4()
{
    Alpha4Press.SetBool("Alpha4Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha5()
{
    Alpha5Press.SetBool("Alpha5Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha5()
{
    Alpha5Press.SetBool("Alpha5Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha6()
{
    Alpha6Press.SetBool("Alpha6Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha6()
{
    Alpha6Press.SetBool("Alpha6Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha7()
{
    Alpha7Press.SetBool("Alpha7Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha7()
{
    Alpha7Press.SetBool("Alpha7Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha8()
{
    Alpha8Press.SetBool("Alpha8Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha8()
{
    Alpha8Press.SetBool("Alpha8Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha9()
{
    Alpha9Press.SetBool("Alpha9Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha9()
{
    Alpha9Press.SetBool("Alpha9Released", true);
}

public void playAlpha0()
{
    Alpha0Press.SetBool("Alpha0Pressed", true);
}

public void stopAlpha0()
{
    Alpha0Press.SetBool("Alpha0Released", true);
}

public void animations()
{
    // ...

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        Alpha1Press.SetBool("Alpha1Released", false);
        playAlpha1();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        Alpha1Press.SetBool("Alpha1Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha1();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
    {
        Alpha2Press.SetBool("Alpha2Released", false);
        playAlpha2();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha2))
    {
        Alpha2Press.SetBool("Alpha2Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha2();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
    {
        Alpha3Press.SetBool("Alpha3Released", false);
        playAlpha3();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha3))
    {
        Alpha3Press.SetBool("Alpha3Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha3();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha4))
    {
        Alpha4Press.SetBool("Alpha4Released", false);
        playAlpha4();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha4))
    {
        Alpha4Press.SetBool("Alpha4Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha4();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5))
    {
        Alpha5Press.SetBool("Alpha5Released", false);
        playAlpha5();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha5))
    {
        Alpha5Press.SetBool("Alpha5Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha5();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha6))
    {
        Alpha6Press.SetBool("Alpha6Released", false);
        playAlpha6();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha6))
    {
        Alpha6Press.SetBool("Alpha6Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha6();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha7))
    {
        Alpha7Press.SetBool("Alpha7Released", false);
        playAlpha7();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha7))
    {
        Alpha7Press.SetBool("Alpha7Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha7();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha8))
    {
        Alpha8Press.SetBool("Alpha8Released", false);
        playAlpha8();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha8))
    {
        Alpha8Press.SetBool("Alpha8Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha8();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha9))
    {
        Alpha9Press.SetBool("Alpha9Released", false);
        playAlpha9();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha9))
    {
        Alpha9Press.SetBool("Alpha9Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha9();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha0))
    {
        Alpha0Press.SetBool("Alpha0Released", false);
        playAlpha0();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha0))
    {
        Alpha0Press.SetBool("Alpha0Pressed", false);
        stopAlpha0();
    }

    // ...
}
```

What's a more effective way to write this? I'm a firm believer in the DRY principle and this is simply TOO much

EDIT:
Image of my keyboard[image]

Comment: To anyone in the close vote queue: note that [the post has been improved](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/252887/revisions).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ how to make this on-topic? Post full code? I want to help OP.

Comment: @aepot The general consensus is that ["_you, as someone who didn't write that code, have no right to do that_"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/974/120114). You've already helped the OP. Unless the OP deletes the question, you should maintain the reputation you've earned from your answer.

Comment: Essential parts of your code are still missing from the question and honestly I doubt this question could/should be salvaged. Perhaps a smaller (actual) project could be used to learn new things that carry over to this project. Perhaps a numeric pad as stand-alone version.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I think only moderators and cleaning bot can delete the answered questions (OP can't). Btw, that makes sense regarding to licensing issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That moment when you know Unity better than C#. I'm on other side: I know nothing about Unity (except docs that I've read while writing this review) but know C# well. Let's merge our knowledge.

- `Animator` is a single animation engine, in other words `GetComponent<Animator>()` always returns the same value, thus you need only one variable to store it.
- `KeyCode` is `enum` ([link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html)) thus you can iterate it with a loop.
- string in format `<KeyCode>+<Pressed/Released>` is good to concatenate these two parts.

The refactored copy of your whole script:

```cs
public class keyboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private string BoolToPressed(bool state)
    {
        return state ? "Pressed" : "Released";
    }

    private void PlayKey(KeyCode keyCode, bool state)
    {
        animator.SetBool(keyCode + BoolToPressed(!state), false);
        animator.SetBool(keyCode + BoolToPressed(state), true);
    }

    private void animations()
    {
        for (KeyCode k = KeyCode.Backspace; k <= KeyCode.Menu; k++)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(k))
                PlayKey(k, true);
            else
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(k))
                PlayKey(k, false);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        animations();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! It worked out really well for the majority of buttons! But some them where left out.. Some miscellaneous such as **Tilde**, **Underscore** and **Å, Ä, Ö**. I don't know which keys they represent on your keyboard but I'll edit the post and attach an image of them. Also some command buttons such as **CAPS, LEFT CTRL, RIGHT ALT GR and RIGHT CTRL** Neither does my **arrows**(up,down,left,right).

All of these chars have the same issue, the debugger claims their boolean parameters for pressed and released doesnt exist but they do. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Kemura refer to `KeyCode` documentation link in my post. You should rename some button animation actions e.g. `ArrowUpPress`/`ArrowUpReleased` to `UpArrowPress`/`UpArrowReleased`, `ÄReleased` to `QuoteReleased`, etc. Must be easy, just make names of animations to match names of buttons in enumeration.